# What model/family should I use?

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution

I am trying to build a model that will predict the number of babies/females (i.e., the response variable is a ratio that is bound between 0 and 2). I started with a simple gaussian model, but there are several observations out at the tail ends of my data range (i.e., at 0 and 2). This leads to a histogram and qq plot that look like:

[image]
[image]

In the histogram the data look approximately normal, but the qq plot suggests that I should not assume normality. Does anyone have any suggestions about what distribution/family might fit this data better or if there is a transformation that might be appropriate? Or whether the normal distribution will indeed work for this data set? Thanks!

Comment: Upload the image properly, please. 1) left click in the drag or drop gray box. 2) select the image to upload. 3) click on the upload button. Note the upload button will only work on those file types permitted as images on this site, convert any image to an acceptable file type of < 2 megabyte size.

Comment: Hi! I went and re-uploaded the images as you said. They appear to be fine in my post are you unable to see them? They are both < 2 MB. I hope they showed up ok this time!

Comment: Good start. Next, you need to include more information. Babies/females does not make any sense by itself. What is this? Is it life births per female in the birthing suite during any particular week at the Children's hospital of Buffalo in 1950? Cough up the nitty-gritty on this, please.

Comment: The histogram does **not** look approximately normal, at all. Knowledge about what the data means and how it was recorded will guide you to a more correct model.

Comment: @Carl at the time imgur wasn't functioning properly. Often correctly uploaded images weren't displaying and new images couldn't be uploaded at all.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, and our apologies to the OP for any difficulties encountered. Also we extend a warm welcome to our new member with the wish for successful collaboration on this site.

Comment: Do you have the number of females (the denominator) in each case, or just the ratio?  If you have both the numerator (babies) and the denominator (females), you could start with babies ~ binomial(females, p).

Comment: this histogram does not tell you what distribution (conditional on covariates) to choose if it's showing the distribution of babies/female for the whole dataset assuming you are trying to do regression.

Comment: also, the spike at zero and the problem description suggests some kind of zero-inflated model. E.g. fit a bernoulli to decide whether a female has one child, then have a distribution for the number of children conditional on whether they are going to have a child or not.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the useful comments! Sorry I did not provide more detailed information. This was my first time posting. The data are based on observations of the number of calves per female moose.

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your data that this is a mixture of several things: The fractional data $0,1/3,1/2,2/3,1,3/2,$ and $2$ as well as more distributed but also likely rational data. It would appear that the data is generated from the ratio of B/F or births (B) per female (F) from a small enough population (of integer numbers) during small enough time periods to cause fractional data to be quite noticeable. It is difficult to model ratios. I would suggest presenting the data either in tabular form as paired numbers, or less usefully by bi-variate plotting of B versus F.

@TheLaconic has suggested a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Example) for this. I think more usefully this is approximately a conditional distribution, for example, a [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). However, as I have never used one, it would really help to have the tabular data for testing.

Comment: This data is from observations of the numbers of calves per moose over a large time period, but each row in the data is at a relatively small spatial scale. It is possible for me to make the spatial scale larger (thus adding more observations per data row) and possibly smoothing the data?

Comment: First, I would list the data as a list consisting of columns of births, females, and regions. Then one models the number of females per region, and then the number of births per female. Another factor could be the size of each regions if available. For example, if the probability of having a number of females in a region is proportional to its size. Lastly, you really need to tell us what information you want to extract from any model. That is what most simplifies getting answers; having a concrete question.

Comment: Seriously, if you want to plot useful things, cluster analysis may be interesting for you, which brings up a point; Why do you want to do this modelling?